# Staking Ethereum

Tags: wallets, proof-of-stake

Brand new investor to crypto but have been reading as much as I can on the space over the past couple months.  I am looking for someone who could help me me a with a step by step guide on how to stake my ether/become a validator once the Constantinople fork happens in January.  I am looking to understand what wallet I need (have a ledger Nano S now), other hardware requirements (raspberry PI?), internet speeds, etc.

I am not technical but would appreciate any additional reading material I could reference.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Thanks - I thought that they were moving to a hybrid pow and pos model with the fork in January.  If Casper is two years away that would be concerning as Dfinity, Tron, etc. are touting they have already addressed the scalability issues and energy problems with mining.  Any thoughts?  Trying to learn as much as I can.  I know that Ethereum by far and away has the biggest Dev community which is promising but won’t developers just move their dapps onto more efficient chains if it takes Ethereum 2 years to release an environment that can support business scalability and cost.

Answer (score 1):

Staking isn't going to be in the Constantinople fork. The list of EIPs that will be included are listed [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pm/wiki/Constantinople-Progress-Tracker). Ethereum wont be moving to Proof of Stake for at least another year, likely 2 years.